# NodeJS - настройка live reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Вопрос - как настроить сервер на NodeJS, чтобы при изменении моделей, контроллеров и других файлов приложение, изменения сразу вступали в силу, а не приходилось выключать dev-сервер с помощью Ctrl+C и заново его запускать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Один из таких скриптов `supervisor`.

`npm install -g supervisor`.
После установки сервер запускаете через него: `supervisor app.js`.

Единственный нюанс - он не увидит вновь созданные файлы. Поэтому если в рабочей папке будет создан новый файл, сервер надо перезапустить

2) Вот нашел еще одну утилиту https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2. Более мощная штука, чем `supervisor`.

После запуска `pm2 start nameFile.js` создает демона -  и консоль, из которой происходил запуск можно закрыть (открепляет работу сервера от консоли). Так же, `pm2` может самостоятельно создать файлы необходимой конфигурации для добавления в автозапуск сервера `NodeJs` (после перезагрузки ОС). Это очень нужная вещь, при работе сервера `NodeJs` на VPS.
Для этого необходимо, после запуска сервера `NodeJs`, написать команду `pm2 startup`, а потом `pm2 save`.

Comment: Спасибо.
То что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

после запускаешь с помощю команды `nodemon <имяФайла>`