# Запуск приложения NodeJS в фоне с указанием NODE_PATH

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, background

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Debian (8) запустить скрипт NodeJS в фоне с указанием ***NODE_PATH*** (`NODE_PATH=. node app`)?

Comment: надо пройти по этому пути где файл и запустить файл...

Comment: @Air как в фоне его запустить-то?

Comment: Мы, по моему о разных вещах говорим...  Или я тебя не понимаю или ты хочешь не понятно что... Что ты имеешь ввиду `запустить в фоне`???

Comment: @Air запустить скрипт в терминале, и со спокойной душой закрыть терминал. и чтобы скрипт после закрытия терминала продолжил работать

Comment: Ну я в `node`  пока сам новичок, Но уверен, что подобное не прокатит...  Вроде никак...

Comment: @Дмытрык, привет, благодарю буду знать....

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать nohup, чтобы запустить скрипт в фоне

```
$ nohup node /nodeapp/index.js &
```

Answer (score 2):

Для указанных целей, я пользуюсь модулем pm2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2. Он не только запустит в фоне, но и перезапустить процесс, при необходимости. Даже после рестарта сервера.
[NodeJS - настройка live reload](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772218/nodejs-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-live-reload/772313#772313)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), который решает вашу проблему.